# Call assembly procedure from another assembly file?

Tags: assembly, x86, procedure, freestanding

Just a simple question:

Let's say I had the following two assembly programs:

## 1:

```
add10:
   add eax, 10
   ret
;call add5 from other file
```

## 2:

```
add5:
   add eax, 5
   ret
;call add10 from other file
```

Could I call `add10` (declared in the first file) from the second file, or vice-versa? If so, how can it be done? (even if it isn't feasible)

NOTE: This will be running on bare metal, not on any fancy NT calls!

Thanks.

Edit: I'm using NASM on Windows.

Comment: To answer this, we need to know what assembler and linker you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both files are linked into the same executable, yes. Lookup EXTERN or EXTRN.

Comment: I tried searching it up, although I couldn't seem to find anything related. Do you have any links?

Comment: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html   Scroll down to EXTERN (6.5). Basically what EXTRN does is tell the assembler that a symbol/label is defined outside of the file.

Answer (score 4):

Two files:

### 1:

```
BITS 32

GLOBAL add5

section .code
add5:
    add eax, 5
    ret
```

### 2:

```
BITS 32

EXTERN add5
EXTERN printf
EXTERN ExitProcess

section .data
    fmt db `eax=%u\n`

section .code
add10:
    add eax, 5
    call add5
    ret

_main:
    mov eax, 87
    call add10

    push eax
    push fmt
    call printf
    add esp, 8

    push 0
    call ExitProcess
```

Assemble & link them together. I used as linker GoLink, other linkers are similar:

```
nasm.exe -fwin32 -o add5.obj add5.asm
nasm.exe -fwin32 -o add10.obj add10.asm
GoLink.exe /ENTRY:_main /console /fo add10.exe add5.obj add10.obj kernel32.dll msvcrt.dll
```

I named the sources "add5.asm" and "add10.asm". The assembler produces "add5.obj" and "add10.obj". The linker uses "add5.obj" and "add10.obj" and some system libraries (for 'printf' and 'ExitProcess'). The result is the executable "add10.exe". Look at the command lines to get the order of those names. The names are arbitrary.

HTH

Comment: Just in case you switch to microsoft assembler (MASM or ML), it uses the directive public instead of global.

Comment: What are the file names? How does the linker know which file to "include" or link? I mean "physically" how does it know which file to open for finding the procedure?