# Calling procedures from another assembly file without warning message

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I have 2 files:

**m2:**

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
global print ;######4######
.code
main:
    MOV AX, @data
    MOV DS, AX

        print proc ;expects information from DX
        MOV AH,9
        INT 21h
        ENDP


    MOV AH, 4ch
    INT 21h
END main
```

**m1:**

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    str1 DB 'hello $'

.code
    EXTRN print:far

main:
    MOV AX, @data
    MOV DS, AX

    MOV DX, OFFSET str1
    CALL print

    MOV AH, 4ch
    INT 21h
END main
```

I tried to figure out how to link the two files using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234898/call-assembly-procedure-from-another-assembly-file) explanation but it is for NASM, while I am using TASM and I had a problem.
I linked both files, but while assembling *m2* I got a warning :

> global type doesn't match symbol : PRINT.

I tried to remove line 4 , but then I couldn't link *m1*, *m2* and recieved a warning :

> undefined symbol PRINT in module M1.ASM

I also tried to remove the keyword `far` from the *m1.asm* file... no use either.

**My question is** how to remove the warning and be able to link the two files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just give the symbol a consistent typing.
The easiest approach is to use `PROC` to let the assembler pick up the correct type:

**m2.asm**

```
...
GLOBAL print: PROC
...
```

**m1.asm**

```
...
EXTRN print: PROC
...
```

Otherwise, you can declare the symbol with type `NEAR` or `FAR` (use it in place of `PROC`), just be sure to properly define the function too (e.g. `print PROC FAR`).

For a complete list of types, see chapter 5 of the [TASM manual](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/borland/turbo_assembler/Turbo_Assembler_Version_5_Users_Guide.pdf).

Comment: @theshopen You are welcome. Beware that one of the pages of the TOC has been glued out of order.